# Robot framework log not generating properly

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

[Screen of the log file which has failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyllF.jpg)

[Screen of the log file which has Passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZqfT.jpg)

I have been working on RobotFramework. As I am new to it, got these problem.
My Test has 17 Test Cases. I Tested it and got log file as shown in image.
Initially it was showing perfect log with all description of each test cases but now I don't know what exactly I have done. It's showing incomplete log with no any description of test case.
How can it might happen:

1. Related to Browser (I'm using Chrome).
2. Or some problem with either Test Suite setup/tear down.

Please point out the exact issue.

Comment: how are u executing it? any command line options used?

Comment: There are obviously results of 9 tests in your (both) logs. Have you tried to expand the log and read/investigate the root cause of failures?

Comment: I have tried to expand but no result. @jan Failed test suit has only 9 test case. passed test suit has 17.

Comment: @Waman Yes, command is 
'jython -m robot robot.html'
same command was working, but not now.

Comment: I have tried to expand but no result. @jan Failed test suit has only 9 test case. passed test suit has 9 too. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: do you see the tests executing in command prompt?, If at all they are executed it should have some logs

Comment: @waman Yes I can see the test execution on Command Prompt, It took time what it used to take. and when I saw the generated report. There are no description of test Keywords.

Comment: Can you try by changing the name of your .html file and the module name? to something else say "sampleRobot"

Comment: @waman , I have done it but not impact.

Comment: The `robot-exit` present in the failed run tag is automatically added when the execution is stopped gracefully - usually by ctrl-c. What happened during the run, did you stop it? What happens if you let it run, and what is written in the console? Please also consider adding a screenshot of log.html.

Comment: Change [log level](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#log-levels) and try again

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue with the Robot framework. I tried to remove the `robotframework.jar` file from my environmental variable `CLASSPATH`. It worked like a charm.

This jar is necessary if you are using robot keyword annotations in your project. Turns out it wasn't necessary at all in my project. If it is in your case, try to update the Jar file by using latest release.

Comment: Thank you 
Have you find any more detail abt it ??

Comment: Sorry. I have debugged this issue at this extent only.